# Good strategy to kill fran in the brawler guild?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Just like to title says whats a good strategy to kill fran in the brawlers guild. I have killed Riddoh but fran ends up killing me. and if i kill Fran, Riddoh kills me. Quite often fran drop a mine or 2 right on top of me insted of a C around me. I play a level 90 frost death knight with an  item level of 464 if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up haveing to burn down Fran hp to about 25% then kill Riddoh. Then quickly used the brawler guild hp potion and burned the rest of frans hp while circleing him carefuly to avoide his dynamites. As for the mines being landed ontop of me stay away from the edges of the ring (rectangle?)

Comment: hmm i thought i did a long time ago